# Друзья, помогите пожалуйста получить значение из $_SESSION

Tags: php, массивы, объекты

Друзья,помогите понять как получить login из массива.
В результате var_dump($_SESSION) вижу, что могу получить login.
`$userAuth = $_SESSION->login;` - получаю ошибку.

> Trying to get property 'login' of non-object

Подскажите пожалуйста,как правильно получить значение.
Прошу не судить строго, не могу нагуглить битый час..новичок((

```
array (size=1)
  'admin' => 
    object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[2]
      public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'RedBeanPHP\OODBBean' (length=19)
      protected 'properties' => 
        array (size=5)
          'id' => string '3' (length=1)
          'login' => string 'qwe' (length=3)
          'email' => string 'qwe@qwe.qwe' (length=11)
          'phone' => string '123' (length=3)
          'password' => string '$2y$10$I2jFMou8H3Yak9rmxVtUA.BRlDDmEOMMrJynJKx2OZjclVg6GRBTu' (length=60)
      protected '__info' => 
        array (size=5)
          'type' => string 'useradmin' (length=9)
          'sys.id' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'sys.orig' => 
            array (size=5)
              'id' => string '3' (length=1)
              'login' => string 'qwe' (length=3)
              'email' => string 'qwe@qwe.qwe' (length=11)
              'phone' => string '123' (length=3)
              'password' => string '$2y$10$I2jFMou8H3Yak9rmxVtUA.BRlDDmEOMMrJynJKx2OZjclVg6GRBTu' (length=60)
          'tainted' => boolean false
          'changed' => boolean false
      protected 'beanHelper' => 
        object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)[3]
          public '__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name' => string 'RedBeanPHP\BeanHelper\SimpleFacadeBeanHelper' (length=44)
      protected 'fetchType' => null
      protected 'withSql' => string '' (length=0)
      protected 'withParams' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'aliasName' => null
      protected 'via' => null
      protected 'noLoad' => boolean false
      protected 'all' => boolean false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Не буду касаться вопроса о целесообразности хранения ORM-объектов в сессии - попытаюсь ответить на заданный вопрос.*

В сессию была сохранена(с ключом `admin`) переменная, содержащая ссылку на объект класса `RedBeanPHP\OODBBean`. В хранилище сессий этот объект хранится в сериализованном виде - сохраняется вся информация для того, чтобы при чтении сессии этот объект можно было инстанцировать заново, в прежнем виде.

В том месте кода, где у вас происходит старт сессии (`session_start();`) - php не знает как инстанцировать объект, т.к. у него есть информации о названии класса - `RedBeanPHP\OODBBean`, но он не знает откуда его загрузить. Поэтому создается неполный объект (`__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name`) со всеми свойствами, но т.к. они `protected` - доступ вы (например, вот так `$_SESSION['admin']->properties['id]`) к ним получить не сможете.

Пакет `RedBeanPHP` использует PSR-4 и наверняка у вас используется `composer`.

Проверьте, что у вас в скрипте, из которого вы показали вывод, правильно подключен файл `vendor/autoload.php`.

===

После того, как проблема с автозагрузкой класса будет решена, доступ к свойству `properties` объекта можно получить так:

```
$props = $_SESSION['admin']->getProperties();
echo $props['id'];
echo $props['login'];
...
```

Comment: Спасибо!))В действительности composer был не установлен и зависимости прописывал сам(простой mvc самопис) Проблема PHP_Incomplete_Class крылась в не правильной инициализации start_session. Решением в моем случае оказалось перенос start_session из входного index.php с подключениями в db.php с конфигурацией подключения для RedBeanPHP. Таким образом теперь у меня есть целостный объект к которому можно обратиться под названием object(RedBeanPHP\OODBBean).Еще раз спасибо!))Буду разбираться дальше)